# Exclude scalacheck from the scala runner's classpath in Scala 2.9.2

Tags: scala, jar, classpath, read-eval-print-loop, scalacheck

A `scalacheck` jar was accidentally included in the standard distribution of Scala 2.9.2, in the `lib` directory, along with the standard scala runtime classes (e.g. `scala-library.jar`). This was [discovered, and fixed](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6121) for subsequent Scala distributions.

I'd like to run the scala 2.9.2 interpreter and use a different version of `scalacheck`, but I can't get it to ignore the version in `lib`.

I tried:

```
$ LOAD_SCALACHECK='import org.scalacheck.Gen; println(Gen.choose(0, 1).sample.get)'
$ scala -e "$LOAD_SCALACHECK"
$ scala -nobootcp -e "$LOAD_SCALACHECK"
$ scala -Dscala.usejavacp=false -e "$LOAD_SCALACHECK"
$ scala -Dscala.usejavacp=false -nobootcp -e "$LOAD_SCALACHECK"
```

All of these still used the `scalacheck.jar`. Is there any way, aside from deleting the jar from `lib`, to run the interpreter excluding a jar from `lib` on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just excise the interloper, at least for a non-SBT-managed Scala... If you did that in a an SBT-managed Scala I'm pretty sure SBT would just put it back.

In the SBT case, you might try revoking all permissions to read that JAR. I don't know what the classloader would do in that case, but one hopes it's robust enough to skip over it and keep looking through the class-path...